# Normalised N.r proof

Tags: linear-algebra

$N$ is the norm of a plane $R$.
$n$ is the normalized position vector of $N$.
$r$ is a position vector from the origin to a point on the plane $R$.

I am coming across repeatedly that $\langle n, r\rangle$ gives the distance of the plane from the origin. I am unable to see a proof.

Could someone show me the proof with emphasis on how and why the normalization changes the equation to $\langle n, r\rangle = d$  from the equation of the plane $\langle N, R \rangle = D$?

Answer (score 0):

Write the equation of the plane as $ \alpha x+ \beta y+ \gamma z + \delta =0 $ . Divide through by $\sqrt{\alpha ^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2}$ to give
$$ ax + by + cz + d =0 $$
 Write $$ n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2}}[\alpha,\beta,\gamma]=[a,b,c] $$
Then $n$ is a unit vector. The direction of the line L through (0,0,0) perpendicular to the plane is $ n=[a,b,c] $ So the parametric equations of the line L are
$$x=at,y=bt,z=ct$$. Substituting into the equation of the plane, and remembering that 
$a^2+b^2+c^2=1 $,we obtain $t=-d$Substituting this value of $t$ into the parametric equations of L, we find that L pierces the plane at $$P_*=(-ad,-bd,-cd)  $$The vector from 
$ P_* $ to the origin is $[ad,bd,cd] $ whose magnitude is $|d|$, i.e. $|d|$is the distance from the origin to the plane. Note that if $r=[x,y,z]$is the position vector of a point 
$(x,y,z)$ on the plane, then $$[a,b,c]\bullet[x,y,z]+d=0,i.e.n\bullet r +d=0. $$

Comment: Thank you. That helps greatly.